# Finding a kernel and an image of $T^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Let $T$ be a linear transformation $T: \mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}^4$ that is defined by:

$$T\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\\u\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\z\\y\\x\end{pmatrix}$$
Find the kernel and image of $T^2$.

I will tell you exactly where i'm stuck, after applying $T$ on $(0,z,y,x)$ i'm pretty
sure i'll be getting $(0,y,z,0)$, to find the kernel i will compare it to $(0,0,0,0)$
which will tell me that $z = 0$ and $y = 0$. Now, this is what i am unsure of, should i write the $z = 0$ and $y = 0$ in the original $T$? should i write it on $(x,y,z,u)$ thus getting $(x,0,0,u)$ or should i forget the original and apply it on $(0,z,y,x)$ thus getting $(0,0,0,x)$. Kind of confused about that little part.
Thanks in advance !

Comment: I have edited your question to fix the formatting. Have a look at it for future reference on how to typeset your questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find $T^2$ first: $$T^2\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \\ u\end{pmatrix} = T\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ z \\ y \\ x\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ y \\ z \\ 0\end{pmatrix},$$ right. So $\ker T^2 = {\rm span}\{ (1,0,0,0), (0,0,0,1) \}$.

> Now, this is what i am unsure of, should i write the z = 0 and y = 0 in the original T ?

Yes, exactly. You are applying $T^2$ in the vector $(x,y,z,u)$. The second step in my calculation above is just that, a step.

> should i write it on (x,y,z,u) thus getting (x,0,0,u) or should i forget the originial and apply it on (0,z,y,x) thus getting (0,0,0,x).

No, by the reason explained above.